# How to retrieve data from firebase realtime database use timestamp?

Tags: javascript, web, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

this is my db structure : https://drive.google.com/open?id=15067yFPeeGoQH9kaagw6vxw-zoDFXmBN

I want to retrieve data from the child "nilai" based on time using timestamp, then enter it into the highchart, I am confused by the code, is my code correct?

```
var startdate = 1552268459655;
var enddate = 1552268535866;
    firebase.database().ref().child("Perangkat2").child("hujan").child("2").child("hujanpermenit").child(data.key).orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startdate).endAt(enddate).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var childData = child.val();
var timestamps=child.val().timestamp;
var nilai=child.val().nilai;
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi @sri dewi sartika, You used `highcharts` tag, but your problem is not related with Highcharts, but rather with firebase. If you have some questions about Highcharts, please provide me with your hard-coded data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var startdate = 1552268459655;
var enddate = 1552268535866;
firebase.database().ref().child("Perangkat2").child("hujan").child("2").child("hujanpermenit").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startdate).endAt(enddate).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
var childData = child.val();
var timestamps=child.val().timestamp;
var nilai=child.val().nilai;
});
});
```

Comment: but i have child random key between child "hujanpermenit" and child "timestamp", how to solve it?

Comment: no need to include that child. The whole snapshot of child "hujanpermenit" is getting using forEach function. don't include random Key in a path that's it.

Comment: I've tried the code, but it's still an error and the data from the child "nilai" hasn't appeared